# How to remove axis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to remove the x and y-axis from the HighCharts and just show only the line in the graph. How do I do it?

Here is my [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9S8Xd/)

Here is my **code**

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {text: ''},
            tooltip: false,
            legend: false,
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: If possible, I want to remove the dots on the line as well. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set gridLineWidth / tickWidth as 0 on both axis and disable labels.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickWidth
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.gridLineWidth

About highcharts.com it is credits parameter: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#credits.enabled

Comment: this is a rather correct way to remove axis as well as remove credits.

Comment: I tried http://jsfiddle.net/9S8Xd/4/ . credits get disabled, but the axis are still not being removed, nor the dots on the line. Thanks

Comment: Add lineWidth as 0, http://jsfiddle.net/9S8Xd/7/, Dots are markers, which need to be also disabled.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote `marker : {enabled : false,},` and it worked. But how do I remove that 3 line segments which enables the option to download the chart

Comment: exporting: {
         enabled: false
},

Answer (score 0):

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9S8Xd/1/

```
    $('#container .highcharts-axis').remove();                      // remove axe
    $('#container .highcharts-axis-labels').remove();               //remove axe label
    $('#container .highcharts-markers.highcharts-tracker').remove();// remove dot
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I remove that triple line segments which on clicking asks me to download the image?

Comment: Its not just ok. Its awesome. Thanks. :)

Comment: One last thing. Can I remove the `Highcharts.com` as well?

Comment: You should see the answer of Sebastian Bochan which is a better way to  do this, i didn't use the api to remove elements, just jquery after loading, but to answer your question with highchart.com http://jsfiddle.net/9S8Xd/3/